# ASP.net MVC2 project in VS2012 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to open MVC2 project in Visual Studio 2012? When I try to load the project I get this error :

> De\De.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was
>   not found. Please try this link for further information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=11&sbp=ProjectTypeDeprecated&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=ProjectCompatibility&o1=F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325

Then I get redirect to : http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading

Do I need to upgrade to MVC3 or I can keep my project in MVC2?

Comment: I ended up re-building the application and importing all my class and views

Comment: sorry that you ended up rebuilding your project. Wish I had run into this issue earlier so I could have provided you with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424080/61654.

Comment: @ahsteele you should post as an answer

Comment: @VinngyG As requested I've [provided an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13652782/61654).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At [VinnyG's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691999/asp-net-mvc2-project-in-vs2012-not-working?lq=1#comment18665880_12691999) I am providing a link to [an answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13424080/61654) on how to fix this issue. [The linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13424080/61654) provides a fully detailed solution but here is a summary:

> [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22079) will need to be downloaded and installed. The MVC 2 project file will need to be modified removing its project GUID. The removal of the project GUID will mean that the project no longer behaves like an MVC project: no right click to add view, controller, etc., but will compile and work as an MVC 2 project without having to migrate.

Comment: Although this seems useful for a lot of people, in my case it didn't work. I used the <ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader> instead and that worked for me! Here you have the link: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008

Comment: I'm interested in finding how an extension could be made to VS2012 to natively handle MVC2 projects like it does for MVC3+. At this time we wouldn't like to risk breaking anything upgrading 2-3 and having to test.

Answer (score 5):

Copied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

If the Model-View-Controller (MVC) project uses version 3 or 4, you can open this project in Visual Studio 2012. By default, Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 supports only MVC 2 and 3, and Visual Studio 2012 supports only MVC 3 and 4. For information about how to automatically upgrade from MVC 2 to MCV 3, see [ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=238178). For information about how to manually upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC3, see [Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project to ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=238179). If your project targets the .NET Framework 3.5 with SP1, you must retarget your project to use the .NET Framework 4.

Comment: the application upgrader is not working once you try to open the solution in VS2012

Comment: the application converter tells me that it does not know what is the project type so I will have to do the conversion manualy