# How to make a project work both in VS 2010 and VS 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2013, csproj

There is an ongoing project that is based on ASP NET MVC 1 and used Visual studio 2010 IDE.
I'm newly joined this project. I want to use Visual studio 2013 IDE for this prject while other developers use 2010 IDE. According to my research to achieve  this goal I made some modification on csproj file. Initial and changed lines are the following:

```
original line:
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>


modified line
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

According to above changes I successfully run it on VS2013. After I checked in new csproj file on TFS, other developers couldn't open project in their IDE VS2010 as expectedly. So in a correct manner, how can I change csproj to use both VS2010 and VS2013 IDEs?

Comment: You may find this useful, and then give more detail in your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

Comment: Also, this looks relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424079/how-do-i-open-an-old-mvc-project-in-visual-studio-2012-or-visual-studio-2013

Comment: The links only about upgrading current version. I already used above solutions and it works fine but I need to use csproj in both VS2010 and VS2013 IDE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424079/how-do-i-open-an-old-mvc-project-in-visual-studio-2012-or-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible.
The only way would be to refrain from checking in the project file, but then it could become tricky if you have "legitimate" modifications to check in.

The general rule is to have a standardized development platform for developers on the same project. Otherwise you end up with this kind of problem.

So basically, either upgrade everyone to VS2013 or stick to VS2010.