# How to upgrade mvc2 to mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got an old project from a friend that he wants me to do redo. How ever that project is written in ASP.net mvc2. So When I try to open it in visual studio 2013 I can errors. Saying the file is incompatible. How would I go ahead and fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to create a new empty MVC 5 project, and move all your files there from old MVC 2 project. If you just try to update DLLs its very hard be sure if you updated all DLLs, proj file, nugets, or at least little bit more work by copying files is well worth it. Problem is that VS2013 is not compatible with old version of MVC framework. 
But, if you really want to open MVC 2 solution in VS2013, you can try following some steps described here: [How do I open an old MVC project in Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424079/how-do-i-open-an-old-mvc-project-in-visual-studio-2012-or-visual-studio-2013) (contains a project Guid that needs to be changed inside .proj file)

Comment: I really need to open it in VIsual Studio 2013 as I not have access to Visual Studio 2010. Thanks for the link you posted i'll try it a tad bit later How ever it seems like I need MVC3 to upgrade to it so I can open it.

Comment: Basically, it boils down to: providing MVC 2 DLLs (if they're not in GAC. You can get them there by installing MVC 2) and modifying .proj file with MVC 2 Guid (close VS, edit .proj in notepad, reopen project).
Also, be aware VS2013 will not recognize that as MVC project, you'll loose some fancy IDE features, like "Add new Controller" menu item, or similar.

Comment: Alright thanks, i'll install visual studio 2010 so I can open the project, and just rebuild it on a empty mvc5 project. seems like the safest thing to do.

Comment: Right sorry, been a while since I were on my laptop and I forgot about this question. Marked it as a answer now.