# have to open ASP.NET MVC3 project in a (MVC3 + MVC4) evnrioment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

it seems ASP.NET MVC3 project cannot be opened in a (MVC3 + MVC4) environment.

we have a shared development environment which has both MVC3 and MVC4 environments (VS2010 and VS2013 on Windows 8.1)
and I was trying to open a MVC3 project using visual studio 2010, and I got an error `"The project type is not supported by this installation."`

I checked project type list in the project file.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Also, I checked the reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll and it is pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll`, and the physical dll does exist.

I have other projects which have `<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>` only,
and they are all loaded fine in VS2010.

it seems the issue is about ASP.NET MVC 3 `{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}` in VS2010 with MVC4 installed.

**I can't upgrade the project and have to use this MVC3+MVC4 environment**.
Any ideas of how to load MVC3 project in a (MVC3 + MVC4) environments?

thanks a lot.

Victor

Comment: Start the Web Platform Installer, install MVC.

Comment: I did try web platform. it shows "the following products were successfully istalled. => ASP.NET MVC3 tools update installer". so the installer doesn't do anything.

Comment: some guys here indicates to upgrade the project. but I can't

Comment: Please read the linked duplicate's answers, and then search the web for "mvc The project type is not supported by this installation", plenty of suggestions.

Comment: Of course, I have read relative threads including this one.

Please read my post, I have {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}; in my project file already, also I tried to launch web platform installed but it shows it’s already installed. I think I am having a different case.

My question to you is,
Should I create a new thread, or follow the old thread?

Comment: Did you install the "visual web designer" component in Visual Studio setup?

Comment: Do you mean MVC visual studio tools or ASP.NET Web Pages, I do have them installed.
I think some registration is broken on this machine, but web platform installer cannot find it.
I have asked other guys stop using the web site and I will try to remove and reinstall MVC3.

Comment: Might be better off creating a new project with MVC5 and copy in all the views and files from the previous project. I give up and just rebuild projects whenever i encounter voodoo errors like this.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. This is an old project, I was told not to change anything on this project (just debugging). I believe, the both MVC platform should be ok on same machine, just need to figure out where is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As CodeCaster suggested, I removed MVC3, and reinstalled, but it doesn't help.

But I found the other way to trigger web platform installer  to 'repair' the environment. I am not sure if this is a typical case, but If you did try all kind of ideas to load a MVC3 project in a MVC3+MVC4 evnriroment, but don't work.
you can try this one.

**my case is** in the project file, we have ASP.NET MVC 3 {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401} in the project type already, and we have **MVC3**, **Visual Studio tools** and **ASP.NET Web Pages** installed, but we still can not load MVC3 project,
the error is "The project type is not supported by this installation.".
and if you launch web platform installer, it tells you "... already installed."

if this is your case, try what we just did, it seems can resolve the issue.

1) manually open the project file, **remove {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401},** **and compile** the project, you should be able to compile the project, because you have MVC3 environment installed.

2) then manually open the project file again, add back {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}, and open project, I remember I waited for about 10 seconds, 
and it showed up a message about missing "Microsoft ASP.NET web Pages - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" (actually in control panel => program list, it got installed already), and ask me to install it using ASP.NET install consol. I clicked yes, after the installation is done, I can open the project and compile it.

Hope this helps your case.

Comment: Also, if you get similar errors, please check this link first, it should resolve most cases. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424079/how-do-i-open-an-old-mvc-project-in-visual-studio-2012-or-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

In general Mvc3 is not supported after VS2010,I use VS2010SP1 btw. 
You may make it work but it will bite you in the end. 
So i recomend choosing matching VS and MVC versions(check the official microsoft site to see the connenction)